# Need help to match specific characters with a Java regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I need to match characters that **do not** belong to the following character set :

> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
>   / - ? : ( ) . , ’ + space

To do that, I'm using this regex :

```
String regex = "[^\\da-zA-Z/\\-\\?:\\(\\)\\.\\,'\\+ ]+";
```

Unfortunatly, that does not work.

I tried this too (negation):

```
String regex = "(?![\\da-zA-Z/\\-\\?:\\(\\)\\.\\,'\\+ ]+)";
```

But it's not ok.

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can use a predefined character class like `\d` *inside* another character class. Also, most of the characters you're escaping aren't special within a character class (although the escaping should be harmless). So:

```
String regex = "[^0-9a-zA-Z/\\-?:().,'+ ]+";
```

Side note: In your question, you said you wanted to replace `’` (a fancy curly apostrophe), but in your regex you have just a normal apostrophe `'`. So change that if needed.

Here's a test:

```
public class RegTest {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        String regex, test, result;

        // First, test without the negation and make sure it *does* replace the target chars
        regex = "[0-9a-zA-Z/\\-?:().,'+ ]+";
        test = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/-?:().,'+";
        result = test.replaceAll(regex, "%");
        System.out.println(result);
        // Prints %

        // Now, test *with* the negation and make sure it matches other characters (I put
        // a few at the beginning) but not those
        regex = "[^0-9a-zA-Z/\\-?:().,'+ ]+";
        test = "[@!\"~abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/-?:().,'+";
        result = test.replaceAll(regex, "%");
        System.out.println(result);
        // Prints %abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/-?:().,'+
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok you're right, but that still does not work. Using string "
"[89897" the special character '[' is not matched.

Comment: @mishka: It is for me, look at the test class I just added. The output of the second test starts with `%abc` telling us that the `[` (along with the `@`, `!`, `"`, and `~`) was matched.

Comment: Ok, the quantifier was not right. It works with "[^0-9a-zA-Z/\\-?:().,'+ ] ?". Thanks !